# RSA Archer Show Filters

Tags: archer

I don't know where to enable the option to show filters in a report. Perhaps a permissions problem? I have tried everything. Anyone does know about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ruben, I assume that you are referring to the filter that shows up beside the name of the field on mouse-over (a funnel symbol), where you type-in a string to filter records.

We cannot apply filters to the reports in RSA Archer. There are no permission problems as you suspect. You can, however, sort the records by clicking on the field name.

The option "Show Filters" appears while adding a record to a cross-reference or a related records field i.e., on clicking "Lookup".

But if you are referring to the filtering of records at the advanced-search level, on the report display page, you can click on 'Modify' and specify your filter criteria in the 'Filters' section.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you, I was wrong. The option "show filters" appears when I edit a record and click on "Lookup" to add a related record.

Comment: I can not upvote your response, please upvote to my question to help me earn enough reputation. Thanks again.